# Sending an email with Spring

Tags: java, email, spring-mvc, jetty

I'm doing a project with Spring MVC and Jetty.

I want to send an email from the application.
Here's what I have so far :

(The class that try to send the email)

```
package horaire;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.mail.MailSender;
import org.springframework.mail.SimpleMailMessage;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service("mailService")
public class Courriel {

@Autowired
private MailSender mailSender;

@Autowired
private SimpleMailMessage mailMessage;

public Courriel(String A, String De, String sujet, String message) {
    mailMessage = new SimpleMailMessage();

    mailMessage.setTo(A);
    mailMessage.setSubject(sujet);
    mailMessage.setFrom(De);
    mailMessage.setText(message);

}
public void Envoyer()
{
    mailSender.send(mailMessage);
}

}
```

(The use)

```
Courriel message = new Courriel("myemail@gmail.com","myemail@gmail.com","Hi","My text");

message.Envoyer();
```

But I get this error :

```
HTTP ERROR 500

Problem accessing /horaire. Reason:

Server Error

Caused by:

java.lang.NullPointerException
at horaire.Courriel.Envoyer(Courriel.java:30)
at ca.ulaval.projetspring.HomeController.horaire(HomeController.java:53)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:212)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:126)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:96)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:617)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:578)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:900)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:827)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:735)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:648)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:455)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:137)
at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:559)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:231)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1072)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:382)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:193)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1006)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:255)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:154)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:365)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:485)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:926)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:988)
at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:635)
at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:235)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:82)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:627)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:51)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:608)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:543)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

I don't understand why it is null.
Do I have to set other parameters? Do I have to modify other files? (one of the XMLs ?)

**Update :** I don't know if it changes anything, I'm using Spring MVC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set up the MailSender's properties for the SMTP server, user name, password, etc.
[Here's an example](http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-sending-e-mail-via-gmail-smtp-server-with-mailsender/).

Comment: I've added the Spring-Mail.xml, but it tells me :  "IOException parsing XML document from class path resource [Spring-Mail.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [Spring-Mail.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist"
I placed it in the same directory as pom.xml

Comment: The linked example uses a ClassPathXmlApplicationContext - that would require that the Spring-Mail.xml file be in the root of the classpath - so in the war file, in WEB-INF/classes. If you're using Maven, that means putting it in src/main/resources. See http://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/index.html#How_do_I_add_resources_to_my_JAR